# задача линейного программирования

Tags: математика

Есть такая задача

```
L = 3*x1 + x2 + x3 -> min
9*x2 + x3 + x4 >= 2
x1 - x2 + x3 - 5*x4 >= 3
x1>=2, x2>=0, x3 <= 0
```

Не совсем понимаю что делать с x3 <= 0, x2 >= 2 - понятно, что это условие неотрицательности. Но вот что делать с x3? 
Думаю сделать вот так x3 + y1 = 0. Но мне кажется, что это делается по другому.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте замену `y3 = -x3`, это сведёт вашу задачу к **основной задаче линейного программирования**.

Тут: [Линейное программирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) можно почитать подробнее, не буду сюда оттуда цитаты копировать.